# Insert a rows to a table and adding a sequence

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am trying to add a sequence and insert a row into my table.

Here is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE AP.dbo.ItemTable
(
   ItemID int NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, 
   ItemDesc varchar(50) NOT NULL
);
```

This is my sequence:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE ItemSEQUENCE AS INT
START WITH 101 INCREMENT BY 10 
MINVALUE 0 MAXVALUE 100000
CYCLE CACHE 25;
```

I am trying to insert this into table:

```
INSERT INTO ItemTable
(ItemID, ItemDesc)
VALUES (NEXT VALUE FOR ItemSequence, '16GB flash drive'),
NEXT VALUE FOR ItemSequence, '"23" HP Monitor');
```

Is this the correct way of creating my code? Also, how would you include quotations in the string? For ex, "23" HP Monitor, did I code it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

If it is SQL Server 2012 or later is then you need to do the following:

```
INSERT INTO ItemTable  (ItemID, ItemDesc)
VALUES 
      (NEXT VALUE FOR ItemSequence, '16GB flash drive')
     ,(NEXT VALUE FOR ItemSequence, '"23" HP Monitor');
```

Comment: Yes it is for SQL Server 2012. But when I tried that code, it gave me an error, "Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'ItemTable'."

Comment: good this query should work then, you missed out the single quotes for your string values and also you need to put one row values between parenthesis `()`

Comment: Yes I am, should i put  INSERT INTO ap.dbo.ItemTable?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer: Should be this

```
 INSERT INTO ItemTable
(ItemID, ItemDesc)
  VALUES (NEXT VALUE FOR ItemSEQUENCE, '16GB flash drive')
INSERT INTO ItemTable
VALUES (NEXT VALUE FOR ItemSEQUENCE, '"23" HP Monitor');
```